# How can I check whether the inputted character is number or not and wanted to raise an error for the same in python?

Tags: python, isnan

How can I check whether the inputted character is number or not and wanted to raise an error for the same in python?

````py
class Error(Exception):
  pass
class ValueTooSmallError(Error):
  pass
class ValueTooLargeError(Error):
  pass
class ValueError(Error):
  pass

number = 10
while True:
    try:
            i_num = float(input("Enter a number: "))
            if i_num < number:
                raise ValueTooSmallError
            elif i_num > number:
                raise ValueTooLargeError
                break
        except ValueTooSmallError:
            print("This value is too small, try again!")
            print()
        except ValueTooLargeError:
            print("This value is too large, try again!")
            print()
        except ValueError: **`this error doesn't reflect`**
            print("Input is not a number")
            print()
    print("Congratulations! You guessed it correctly.")
    ```
````

Comment: I am raising exception and also printed statement but I am unable to put the condition for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is not a number, it raises [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError). As such, adding another except statement to catch a `ValueError` would catch the case when the inputted string is not  proper float.

Comment: Still it doesn't work in the code.

Comment: I believe this is because you are *redefining* `ValueError` in your own code. `ValueError` is a standard exception provided by Python for catching incorrect string-to-number errors (and others), but your own definition of `ValueError` is masking it, so that you can't catch the one that Python is throwing. Just remove your definition of `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are typecasting the given input to float, that statement it self throws an error if given input is not a number.
Ex: float('a') gives following error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'". So you need to add that exception in your code.